# WSO2 Identity Server 3.2.3. Missing Ability to Add External User Stores

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

What happened to the ability to add an external user store with custom tables in WSO2 Identity Server 3.2.3?

We are evaluating use of this IS and it appears an older version had this capability and the latest version does not.

Am I missing a configuration setting or has this capability been completely removed?  Or is this a build configuration option?

Not having this feature is a show-stopper.

Comment: I know, I am having troubles with configuring the user-mgt.xml manually .... very error prone

Comment: Configure an External JDBC User Store : http://wso2.org/project/solutions/identity/3.2.3/docs/user-core/admin_guide.html#JDBC    Configure an External LDAP User Store  : http://wso2.org/project/solutions/identity/3.2.3/docs/user-core/admin_guide.html#LDAP

Answer (score 0):

it's done through the config files - there is (seemingly) no ui component. I was able to connect to an external sql server user store via jdbc by manipulating the user-mgt.xml and master-datasource.xml files. Although next step would be to define a logical schema definition to map the id fields. e.g. running the mssql.sql script in /dbscripts on my sql server db will create the needed structure.